# Win32 Cannot LoadImageW at runtime

Tags: windows, winapi

Trying to use Win32 API to load an icon for an application.

```
case WM_CREATE: {
auto hIcon = LoadImageW(NULL, L"C:\\icon.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
if (hIcon) {
    SendMessage(handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon);
} else {
    auto lastError = GetLastError();
    MessageBox(handle, L"Could not load icon!", L"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}
}
```

What I get is the message box as above, with lastError being 0. The icon is located at the absolute path specified, and if the file is renamed such that the path is invalid last erorr code is 2 (file not found). Therefore, I assume the icon is found.

What I've tried:

- Playing with relative paths.
- Saving in different file formats, .png and .bmp, using Windows Paint, to avoid improper format errors.
- Adding different flags, such as `LR_LOADTRANSPARENT`.
- handle is NULL or GetModuleHandle(NULL)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242193/loadimage-returns-null-and-getlasterror-returns-0

Comment: @HansPassant I found that link, but the answer does not apply. This is blank window. https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2097

Comment: .ico is a different format than .bmp or .png.

Comment: I used your code to load an existing icon and it works fine. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAt7b.png.

  You have to make sure the type of file is ICO file.

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaVFj.png.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, and all of them should work with the same API AFAIK. However, none of them works.

Comment: I also tried loading the flutter icon from 'windows\runner\resources\app_icon.ico' and set size to 64x64. This is surely a correct icon because it works in flutter apps built for Windows. Still doesn't work. Could it be a bug in Windows SDK?

Comment: It generates hIcon when the type of resource is bitmap: ` LoadImageW(NULL, L"C:\\icon.ico", IMAGE_BITMAP, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);` However, this returns a bitmap, not an icon, so the icon is not applied and the last error is again 0.

Comment: Flutter does not use icons, it uses bitmaps.  The term "icon" survived from early web design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image must be an `.ico` file in some specific format. The one which worked correctly for me was exporting it from GIMP with 'Windows Icon' format selected. The icon was previously in the .ico format, it just wasn't right for some reason. Examples which load it from .bmp and .png did not work for me, that works only for bitmaps, which are not icons.

If the file is found, and the formats are not correct, there won't be anything in last error.

Comment: Unfortunately there's absolutely nothing to prevent you from saving a file with the wrong extension, and as you've found the extension means squat.

Comment: No, I am not talking about extensions. The program used to create the non-working file created a valid icon and gave it .ico extension. I used this icon as favicon for a web page and it worked fine. It is about Windows API not accepting all icons and not giving any errors when it fails to accept one.

Comment: Favicons are a poor way of testing an icon. Web browsers recognize basically any valid image format to display as an icon, unlike the Windows API.

Comment: `LoadImageW` will accept **any** valid .ico file. The issue is with the authoring software, that more often than not cannot produce a valid file, in any supported format ([there are many](https://www.google.com/search?q=ico+site%3Adevblogs.microsoft.com%2Foldnewthing)).